# How to send user to a different activity (intent is not working)

Tags: android, kotlin

**In this code, I would like to send the user to a different activity when they hit the see more button in the dropdown menu but when I try and run the line `startActivity(Intent(this,home::class.java ))` I get an error that says none of the following function can be called with the argument supplied **

````
            var name:TextView
            var mbNum:TextView
            var mMenus:ImageView


            init{
                 name = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mTitle)
                 mbNum = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mSubTitle)
                 mMenus = v.findViewById(R.id.mMenus)
                 mMenus.setOnClickListener{popupMenus(it)}
            }


            private fun popupMenus(v:View){
                val position =userList[adapterPosition]
                val popupMenus = PopupMenu(c,v)
                popupMenus.inflate(R.menu.show_menu)
                popupMenus.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                    when(it.itemId){
                        R.id.seeMore->{

                            startActivity(Intent(this,home::class.java )
                            Toast.makeText(c,"View More is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            true
                        }

                        R.id.delete->{
                            Toast.makeText(c,"Delete is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            true
                        }

                        else-> true
                    }

                }
                popupMenus.show()
                val popup = PopupMenu::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
                popup.isAccessible = true
                val menu = popup.get(popupMenus)
                menu.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon",Boolean::class.java)
                    .invoke(menu,true)
            }



    }```
````

Comment: `this` probably is not a `Context`.

Comment: How would I make it a context

Comment: It looks like `c` is a `Context`. Otherwise, `v.getContext()` will be a `Context`.

Comment: You can call it like `startActivity(Intent(c, home::class.java )` or `startActivity(Intent(v.context, home::class.java )`

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
      startActivity(Intent(this,home::class.java )
```

to

```
startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,home::class.java )
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error

Comment: private fun popupMenus(v:View,context:Context)
pass context on fun
startActivity(Intent(context,home::class.java )